# How to integrate with Grammarly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, grammarly

I'm have a service where users write literature. I'm encouraging them to use third party services like Grammarly to check the texts. But I'm using contentEditable and Grammarly doesn't seem to trigger in all views. Any ideas on how to call Grammarly or make Grammarly trigger for specific DOM elements?

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Then this happened..."></div>
```

Comment: Did you try ckEditor jquery plug-in?

Comment: Can you provide code that doesn't work?

Comment: @NitinDhomse No, but I'm looking for a markup solution.

Comment: @br3t Sure, adding it now. But it's not a bug, I'm looking for something to trigger Grammarly specifically for this area.

Comment: @JesperBylund : ckEditer gives you  underlined markup for a text, if something is wrong.

Comment: @NitinDhomse Thanks but i'm looking for a solution specifically for Grammarly.

Comment: @JesperBylund, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @OytunTez No, Grammarly never responded and I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it's possible to integrate via [Grammarly Text Editor SDK](https://developer.grammarly.com/docs/) in really straightforward and clean way.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/grammarly/javascript-plugin/tree/main/examples/editor-sdk-react?file=/src/Editors.js) is editor SDK React example.

Comment: Head up, Grammarly SDK is deprecated: https://developer.grammarly.com/sdk-deprecation

Answer (score 7):

You can enable initialization of Grammarly extension by special attribute: `data-enable-grammarly="true"`

You can find more information about this attribute [here](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/616#issuecomment-343596615).